# Chess board Expo app - Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault

Tags: react-native

I forked a chess board expo repository in React Native. I ran the following that can be copy-and-pasted:

```
git clone git@github.com:SmallChess/react-native-chessboard.git
cd react-native-chessboard/example
yarn install
npm start --reset-cache
```

I'm getting an error while trying to run it on the iOS simulator - `Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault from /Users/scchess/Sources/react-native-chessboard/src/index.tsx: @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault could not be found within the project`.

I tried the following:

```
npm add @babel/runtime
npm install
```

and then restart Metro, but same error. I have no idea how to resolve it.

```
npm --version
10.2.3

expo --version
6.3.10
```